Error al enviar datos con php y ajax
Al realizar un procedimiento de mi codigo obtengo este error y se imprime en la pantalla
Warning: Undefined array key "id" in C:\xampp\htdocs\PortalFactura\tablas\tablaAF.php on line 6
Pero al inspeccionar la pagina veo que si hay una respuesta
Uso esta funcion para obtener un numero que posteriormente pasare a otro archivo mediante ajax
function obtenerNumero(num) {
    //alert(num)
    $.ajax({
        url: "tablas/tablaAF.php",
        type: "POST",
        data: {
            id: num // <- insertas la id
        },
        success: function(r) {
            console.log(r);
        }
    });
}


Y aqui es donde lo recibe
<?php
    require_once "../clases/conexion.php";
    $obj = new conectar();
    $conexion = $obj->conexion();

        $id = $_POST['id'];

        $sql = "select Alumnos.id, Alumnos.Nombre, Alumnos.ApellidoP, Alumnos.ApellidoM, Alumnos.CURP from padrehijo JOIN Alumnos ON padrehijo.idHijo = Alumnos.id where padrehijo.idPadre = '$id'";

    $result = mysqli_query($conexion, $sql);
    
?>

Ya intente de todo, todo se envia correctamente, hice que se imprimiera un console.log y aparecio todo el codigo necesario para que se mostrara lo que yo quiero

Depura con las funciones var_dump($_POST); die; o print_r($_POST); die;. Esto te mostrará en la consola si realmente está llegando el id al servidor de PHP o si está llegando vacío.

El error es claro en cuanto al problema.
Warning: Undefined array key "id" in C:\xampp\htdocs\PortalFactura\tablas\tablaAF.php on line 6

Dice "Advertencia: Clave de arreglo indefinida "id" en..."
La clave de arreglo, es $_POST['id'];, siendo la clave "id" y el arreglo $_POST. Que significa esto entonces? que la variable como tal, no nos ha llegado y eso es un problema con el envío.
Primero lo primero, vamos a realizar una validación correcta de $_POST['id']; para entender el error nosotros mismos con nuestro propio manejo de errores.
//Verificamos si "id" esa definida en $_POST y si esta misma no esta vacia
if (isset($_POST['id']) && !empty($_POST['id'])) {
    $id = $_POST['id']; //Luego, cargamos la variable
    //Luego sigue el resto de tu codigo
} else {
    //Retornamos un error si el "id" no cumple las condiciones
    echo json_encode(['error' => 'El ID no fue recibido o esta vacio']);
}

Ahora, para el envío realizaremos las siguientes modificaciones, mismo caso, para manejar de mejor manera los errores.
function obtenerNumero(num) {
    if (!num) {
        console.error('El número proporcionado no es válido.');
        return;
    }
    
    $.ajax({
        url: "tablas/tablaAF.php",
        type: "POST",
        data: {
            id: num // <- insertas la id
        },
        success: function(r) {
            console.log('Respuesta del servidor:', r);
        },
        error: function(err) {
            console.error('Error en la llamada AJAX:', err);
        }
    });
}

Ahora por partes:
Agregamos una validación para num, de este modo vemos que num sea válido.  AL verificar que num no sea falso, estamos revisando que no sea undefined, null, false, 0, NaN (not a number/no un numero), o empty/vacio.
Agregamos también una respuesta más detallada, y el manejo del Ajax en caso de error.
